# Apache Camel: Consume from Bean

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have a question about how to invoke a bean as an uri like this:

```
from("bean:MyBeanCall?method=beancallMethod(String1)")
```

The Consumer has to be dynamic and returns the URI as a String from the bean. Inside the bean I want also use the @Header Annotation to add some Header properties.

The working bean call looks like this:

```
.bean(MyBeanCall.class,"beancall('String1')");
```

The bean looks like this:

```
public static void beancall(String test, @Header("theHeader") String header, @Header("JMSCorrelationID") String correlationID){...}
```

But I need the call inside the `from()` to generate the consumer with the String1 and the Headers.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation http://camel.apache.org/bean.html

> A bean: endpoint cannot be defined as the input to the route; i.e. you
>   cannot consume from it, you can only route from some inbound message
>   Endpoint to the bean endpoint as output. So consider using a direct:
>   or queue: endpoint as the input.

Depending on your requirements, you can use a timer, a scheduleRoutingPolicy, a SimpleScheduleRoutingPolicy or a CronScheduleRoutingPolicy to trigger the route.

Comment: Hi,

first of all thanks for your answer.

I found out, that I can use an instance of an object in the from URI.
For example:

from(instance.method("String1"))

But in this case I have no possibility to pass the headers.
I need the camelid and the routeid, too.

There must be a solution.

My Requirements:

Build the Consumer (for a topic) in a bean an retuen the consumer String to the from URI.

Comment: But in that case why don't you inject the bean as a property from your blueprint.xml instead? Then use the annotation @BeanInject to String variable. Then you just do from(variable) where variable contains your URI.